# Repeat a test case for different values in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, loops, jasmine, bdd

I have the following code in controller

```
$scope.changeForm = function(num,fromLink){
        $scope.userEmail_sign = '';
        $scope.pass_sign = '';
        $scope.normalizeMessages(fromLink);
        $scope.userEmail_reg = '';
        $scope.npi = '';
        $scope.password_reg = '';
        $scope.confirmPassword_reg = '';
        $scope.userEmail_forgotPwd = '';
        $scope.formCode = num;
        if(num == 2){
            $location.path("/auth/register");
        }else if (num == 3){
            $location.path("/auth/forgot-password");
        }else if (num == 1){
            $location.path("/auth/sign-in");
        }
    };
```

And I'm trying to write a test case to to test for values 1,2 and 3.
Following is the test case code so far written

```
describe('function: changeForm',function(){
        var formNames = ['sign in form','registration form','forgot password form'],
        paths = ['/auth/sign-in','/auth/register','/auth/forgot-password'],
        num,
        currentPath;
        beforeEach(function(){
            $scope.changeForm(num);
            currentPath = $location.path();
        })

        for(num = paths.length; num >=1;num--){
            it('should make all the input fields empty and show '+formNames[num-1],function(){
                expect($scope.userEmail_sign).toBe('');
                expect($scope.pass_sign).toBe('');
                expect($scope.userEmail_reg).toBe('');
                expect($scope.npi).toBe('');
                expect($scope.password_reg).toBe('');
                expect($scope.confirmPassword_reg).toBe('');
                expect($scope.userEmail_forgotPwd).toBe('');
                expect($scope.formCode).toBe(num);
                expect(currentPath).toBe(paths[num-1]);
            });
        }
    });
```

For the loop placed I'm getting the following error when I ran the test case.

```
Expected '/auth/register' to be undefined.
```

What am I missing to make this work?